# How do I get rid of a specific element in a magento template?

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, magento

I have a Magento site, with a paid template implemented in it. My problem is this:
The top navigation bar works perfectly on any browser other than the latest IE versions. On those versions it does not appear. This seems to be the result of 'strong' tags around the text in the naviation bar. How do I get rid of these tags? or replace them?

Comment: Which tags are you talking about?

Comment: 'strong' tags. the editor must have recieved it as html. my bad

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide a link. Last time I did that I was accuesd of commecring.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to edit the appropriate .phtml file for your template to remove the tags.  Magento can assist you in finding this with the developer client's "Template Path Hints" setting.  This is done from `System -> Config -> Advanced -> Developer`.

[image: Enabling Template Path Hints]

Step 1:  Select your store/site from the dropdown menu.
Step 2: (Optional, but recommended) Enter your IP address, otherwise your site is going to get ugly for everyone for a few minutes.
Step 3:  Enable Template Path Hints.  If you don't see this option, you haven't selected your site from step 1.

With Template Path Hints enabled, refresh your site and you should see a bunch of lovely red boxes around various elements of your page.  Find the one attached to your navigation menu, and it will display the path to its .phtml file.  Armed with the knowledge of which file you need to edit, you can disable Template Path Hints and go remove those strong tags.

Make sure to refresh your cache (`System -> Cache Management`) to see any changes you've made take effect.

Comment: Thank you for answering, Don!
I followed your steps - once with my IP typed in and another time with an empty box: yet on both times I didn't see any lovely red boxes around the elements. I did delete my cahce. 
Anything else I should do?

Comment: Well if you're seeing the "Template Path Hints" box available to change, it should be working.  Another possibility is the wrong configuration scope chosen from step 1.

Comment: The box is available for change, And I could not have done the first stage wrong, since I have only one configuration scope